# rails esサイト　カート機能とオーダー機能での不具合

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsは勿論プログラミング初心者です。

今回「Railsによるアジャイルwebアプリケーション開発（第４版）」という本を参考にしてecサイトアプリを作っているのですが、記述通りに作成しているのに不具合が起きて自分では対処できないので質問させていただきました。

手順としましては、簡単な商品投稿と一覧と詳細が見れるサイト作り、カート機能追加し、オーダー機能を追加という感じです。
カート機能追加まではうまくいってたのですが、オーダー機能の追加の際にカートに商品を入れられなくなる現象が起こりました。controllerはapplication,orders,carts,line_items,store,productsの６つ。modelは、order,cart,line_item,productの４つです。問題箇所だと思われる中身を載せてみます
・carts_controller.rb

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
              # before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

              def index
                @carts = Cart.all

                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html # index.html.erb
                  format.json { render json: @carts }
                end
              end

              def show
                begin
                    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
                rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
                    logger.error "無効なカート#{params[:id]}にアクセスしようとしました"
                    redirect_to store_url, notice: '無効なカートです'
                else
                    respond_to do |format|
                        format.html #show.html.erb
                        format.json { render json: @cart }
                    end
                end
              end

              def new
                @cart = Cart.new

                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html # new.html.erb
                  format.json { render json: @cart }
                end
              end

              def edit
                @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])

              end

              def create
                @cart = Cart.new(params[:cart])

                respond_to do |format|
                  if @cart.save
                    format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
                    format.json { render json: @cart, status: :created, location: @cart }
                  else
                    format.html { render :new }
                    format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                  end
                end
              end

              def update
                @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])

                respond_to do |format|
                  if @cart.update_attributes(params[:cart])
                    format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
                    format.json { head :ok }
                  else
                    format.html { render :edit }
                    format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                  end
                end
              end

              def destroy
                @cart = current_cart
                @cart.destroy
                session[:cart_id] = nil
                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to store_url }
                  format.json { head :ok }
                end
              end

              # private

              #   def set_cart
              #     @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
              #   end

              #   def cart_params
              #     params.fetch(:cart, {})
              #   end
            end
```

・orders_controller.rb

```
      class OrdersController < ApplicationController
              def new
                @cart = current_cart
                if @cart.line_items.empty?
                    redirect_to store_url, notice: "カートは空です"
                    return
                end

                @order = Order.new

                respond_to do |format|
                    format.html
                    format.json { render json: @order }
                end
              end

              def create
                @order = Order.new(params[:order])
                # @order = params[:order].permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type)
                # Order.new(@order)
                @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

                respond_to do |format|
                    if @order.save
                        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
                        session[:cart_id] = nil
                        format.html {redirect_to store_url, notice: 
                            'ご注文ありがとうございます＾＾'}
                        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order}
                    else
                        @cart = current_cart
                        format.html {render action: "new"}
                        format.json {render json: @order.errors,
                            status: :unprocessable_entity}
                    end
                end
              end

              def index
                @orders = Order.all

                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html
                  format.json { render json: @orders }
                end
              end

              def show
                @order = Order.find(params[:id])

                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html
                  format.json { render json: @order }
                end
              end

              def edit
                @order = Order.find(params[:id])
              end

              def update
                @order = Order.find(params[:id])

                respond_to do |format|
                  if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
                    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
                    format.json { head :ok }
                  else
                    format.html { render action: "edit" }
                    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                  end
                end
              end

              def destroy
                @order = Order.find(params[:id])
                @order.destroy

                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
                  format.json { head :ok }
                end
              end
            end
```

・line_items_controller.rb

```
 class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
              before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

              def index
                @line_items = LineItem.all
              end

              def show
                @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])

                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html # show.html.erb
                  format.json { render json: @line_item }
                end
              end

              def new
                @line_item = LineItem.new

                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html # new.html.erb
                  format.json { render json: @line_item }
                end
              end

              def edit
                @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
              end

              def create
                @cart = current_cart
                product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
                @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

                respond_to do |format|
                  if @line_item.save
                    # format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
                    format.html { redirect_to store_url}
                    format.js { @current_item = @line_item}
                    format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
                  else
                    format.html { render action: "new" }
                    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                  end
                end
              end

              def update
                @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])

                respond_to do |format|
                  if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
                    format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
                    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
                  else
                    format.html { render :edit }
                    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                  end
                end
              end

              def destroy
                @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
                @line_item.destroy
                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
                  format.json { head :no_content }
                end
              end

              def decrease
                @cart = current_cart
                @line_item = @cart.decrease(params[:id])

                respond_to do |format|
                    if @line_item.save
                        format.html{redirect_to store_url}
                        format.json{head :ok}
                    else
                        format.html{render action: "edit"}
                        format.json{render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
                    end
                end
              end

              def increase
                @cart = current_cart
                @line_item = @cart.increase(params[:id])

                respond_to do |format|
                    if @line_item.save
                        format.html{redirect_to store_url}
                        format.json{head :ok}
                    else
                        format.html{render action: "edit"}
                        format.json{render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
                    end
                end
              end

              private
                def set_line_item
                  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
                end

                def line_item_params
                  params.fetch(:line_item, {})
                end
            end
```

・cart.rb

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
                has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

                def add_product(product_id)
                    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
                    if current_item
                        current_item.quantity += 1
                    else
                        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
                    end
                    current_item        
                end

                def decrease(line_item_id)
                    current_item = line_items.find(line_item_id)
                    if current_item.quantity > 1
                        current_item.quantity -= 1
                    else
                        current_item.destroy
                    end
                    current_item
                end

                def increase(line_item_id)
                    current_item = line_items.find(line_item_id)
                    current_item.quantity += 1
                    current_item        
                end

                def total_price
                    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
                end
            end
```

・order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
                PAYMENT_TYPES = ["現金","クレジットカード","注文書"]
                has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy


                validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
                validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES

                def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
                    cart.line_items.each do |item|
                        item.cart_id = nil
                        line_items << item
                    end
                end
            end
```

・line_item.rb

```
            class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
                belongs_to :order
                belongs_to :product
                belongs_to :cart

                def total_price
                    product.price * quantity
                end
            end
```

以上です。

色々試してみたところ、line_item.rbのbelongs_to :orderを消すとカート機能はうまくいきます。ですがオーダー機能がうまく行かなくなるので、やはりbelongs_to :orderは必要なのかなと思ってきてはいるのですがどうしたらいいものか。。。という現状です。

ちなみにカートに追加した時のターミナルの記述には rollback transaction　が発生しております。
後、参考にしている本ではscaffoldを使っているのですが自分はscaffold使わないようにしていますのでそのら辺での不具合もあるのかもしれません。

以上です。気になるところなどアドバイスいただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いしますm(_ _)m

Comment: 「カートに商品を入れられない」というのはどういう状況なのでしょうか。そのときのログはどうなっているのでしょうか。デバッグ丸投げ質問はこのサイトではあまり好まれません。

Comment: この手の本って、ソースコードがダウンロードできると思うんですけど。 https://www.ohmsha.co.jp/book/9784274068669/ これと比較するというのは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！ブラウザ上では何も変わらずただカートに入れられないという状況で、カートに入れた際のターミナル上のメッセージ内に（rollback transaction）という赤文字が出て来ているという感じです。
ソースコードは

Comment: 途中切れたので続きです↓
ソースコードは勿論ダウンロードして比較もしてみました。scaffoldの有無もあったとまだ自分の知識が浅いというのもあり特におかしなところは見つけられませんでした。
あれから数日試行錯誤して一応の自己解決に至れたと思うので最後に書かせていただきます。

最終的にはline_itemとorderのアソシエーションを外して、orders_controllerのcreateにOrder.newを入れるオブジェクトを１つ増やしてそれを中継するような形で今の所解決できた気がします。


　　　　　アットorder = params[:order].permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type)
   　　　アットexample = Order.new(@order)
   　　　アットexample.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました。コメント欄にしか書いていなかったので回答します

line_itemとorderのアソシエーションを外して、`orders_controller`のcreateに`Order.new`を入れるオブジェクトを１つ増やしてそれを中継するような形で今の所解決できた気がします。

```
＠order = params[:order].permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type)
＠example = Order.new(@order)
＠example.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
```

ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m

それと別のやり方ですが、アソシエーションが必要な場合。そのままの記述で、line_itemがcreateの際に`@line_item.save(validate: false)`と記述します。saveの時のvalidateを外すというやり方です。こちらの方が自分的には都合良かったのであとで変えました！